# .Net Async Page Declaration set to true as the default, are there performance issues with this?

Tags: .net, sitecore, httphandler

I have an ecommerce site and on the final checkout page when the customer clicks "Place Order" I want to send the order confirmation email using SmtpClient SendAsync:

```
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
client.SendAsync(mailMessage, null);
```

But it appears I need to have the "Async" page declaration set to true:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ydy4x04a.aspx

If my checkout page had its own .aspx page I'd have no issue with this, but because I'm using Sitecore CMS then there is only one .aspx page for the entire site (instead the site has many .ascx controls which Sitecore assigns to the .aspx).

So because I only have one .aspx page then this setting change will be applied across the entire site. Are there any performance issues with this? The only reason I ask is because the default is set to false.

Comment: Out of curiosity, how many emails are you sending at once and how much of a delay are you getting? It sounds like you're just sending a confirmation email and I'm curious as to how long that is halting your thread.

Comment: Its just the one email to the customer. But this same process also is handling the credit card verification, in-stock checks, DB updates, etc., so any area where we can make an async call would be help.

Comment: Just a quick info - you can have all the aspx pages you want in a Sitecore solution. Just create a new layout in the developer center, and make sure to set the new layout on the presentation details on the desired items.